# Optimizing Async Batch Processing for AWS CloudWatch Log Downloads Using aioboto3 in Python

Tags: python, concurrency, boto3

I have a Python script that downloads and saves AWS CloudWatch logs.
I utilize `aioboto3` and `asyncio` for concurrency to maximize my runtime results. However, I am not sure about my approach and would love to get more recommendations for improvement and optimization.

I think AWS's max throttling is around `30` requests per second. I found that I have the best results with running around `25` requests concurrently. Running over `25` coroutines yields a `ThrottelingException`.
I configured the `max_attempts` to be `6` in the `retries` dict inside the `config`. Running `25` coroutines seems to do the job; however, when running more coroutines, an exception is raised, and I effectively lose data since no more retries will be made in the context of that request.

Also, I use a `semaphore` to control the concurrent requests as best as possible, mainly to avoid getting `ThrottlingException`s. I also use batch processing of `25` coroutines per batch. Each coroutine is a daily query search inside the destined log group.

Why daily? because I found out that it is way faster than querying ranges of days, weeks, months, etc. Also, it gives me more granular control over when I can stop running batches (for example, from a certain batch and forward, I do not have any logs, so I can stop once the first batch fails...)

I also tried increasing the value of `max_pool_connections,` but it seems to give the best result when being set to `10` (which I think is the default value anyway), so it is pretty weird.

Lastly, I thought about spawning a process for each log group, but it seems redundant since AWS will still limit my requests to `30` per second (I think), and Python's GIL will not allow me to run more than two threads at the same time anyways, so it seems like this has no use at all.

I would love to get some idea

Here's a short demonstration of my script:

````py
import asyncio

import aioboto3
from botocore.config import Config
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError


async def fetch_logs(semaphore, session, start_time, end_time, log_group_name):
    async with session.client(service_name='logs', region_name='us-east-1',
                              config=Config(
                                  {"retries": {"max_attempts": 6, "mode": "standard"},
                                   "max_pool_connections": 10})) as logs_client:
        async with semaphore:
            try:
                start_query_response = await logs_client.start_query(
                    logGroupName=log_group_name,
                    startTime=int(start_time.timestamp()),
                    endTime=int(end_time.timestamp()),
                    queryString="some_query")

                query_id = start_query_response['queryId']
                response = None
                while response is None or response['status'] == 'Running':
                    # Simple polling:
                    await asyncio.sleep(1)
                    response = await logs_client.get_query_results(queryId=query_id)

            except ClientError as e:
                print(f"An error occurred: {e}")


async def main():
    session = aioboto3.Session(profile_name="profile_name", region_name="us-east-1")
    log_groups = get_log_groups()  # Get log groups from somewhere
    if log_groups:
        for log_group in log_groups:
            # Define the end_date as today and start going backwards
            today = datetime.now()
            absolute_start_date = today - timedelta(days=730)  # Go 2 years back
            current_end_date = today

            semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(25)
            while current_end_date > absolute_start_date:
                batch_coroutines = []
                for _ in range(25):
                    current_start_date = current_end_date - timedelta(days=1)
                    if current_start_date <= absolute_start_date:
                        break
                    batch_coroutines.append(
                        fetch_logs(semaphore, session, current_start_date, current_end_date, log_group_name)
                    )
                    current_end_date = current_start_date
                await asyncio.gather(*batch_coroutines)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main()) ```
````